# Twilio conference sid not getting in params using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

using twilio am making conference room. I successfully created the conference between two users. But i can't able to get conference sid from twilio. Can any one please help me in that.

```
twiml1 = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say "You have joined the conference."
    r.Dial do |d|
      d.Conference "#{conference_title}",
        waitUrl: " ",
        muted: "false",
        startConferenceOnEnter: "true",
        endConferenceOnExit: "true",
        maxParticipants: 5,

    end
  end
```

This is how am connecting connecting conference in between two user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You don't get the parameters for the Conference SID at this point because you could well be creating the conference with the return of this TwiML. Instead, there are a couple of other ways to get the SID.

#### Conference events

With the [`statusCallback` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallback) on the [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) element you can set a URL to receive various events as webhooks regarding the conference (pick those events with the [`statusCallbackEvent` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent)). You could listen for the start event and you will receive the Conference SID as a parameter in the webhook request.

#### Checking the REST API

Otherwise, you can make an API call to the REST API [Conference resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference).

You can search for your conference by the name you give it. For example, you can [search for the conference called "MyRoom"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference#list) using the following Ruby (if you have the [twilio-ruby gem](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/ruby) installed):

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN

# Loop over conferences and print out the SID for each one
@client.account.conferences.list({
  :status => "in-progress",
  :friendly_name => "MyRoom"}).each do |conference|
  puts conference.sid
end
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

**[edit]**

#### An example of the statusCallback in Rails.

First I'm going to adjust the TwiML you used initially:

```
  twiml1 = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say "You have joined the conference."
    r.Dial do |d|
      d.Conference "#{conference_title}",
        waitUrl: " ",
        muted: "false",
        startConferenceOnEnter: "true",
        endConferenceOnExit: "true",
        maxParticipants: 5,
        statusCallback: "/conferences/callback",
        statusCallbackEvent: "start"
    end
  end
```

I've added the `statusCallback` attribute with a path to an action in your Rails application (you can use whatever path you want, I just made this up for now). I also added the `statusCallbackEvent` attribute with the value "start". There are [other events](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent) available, but to get the SID, the start event will do.

Now we need an action to receive that callback.

```
class ConferencesController < ApplicationController
  def callback
    # Do something with the conference SID.
    Rails.logger.info(params["ConferenceSid"])
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

You'll need to point a POST route at that controller action too, but I'll leave that up to you to sort out.

Comment: Hi philnash is there any possible to get the conference id when conference ended. Because i need to calculate the price based on the total duration of the conference call.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to use statusCallbackEvent using ruby on rails.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay philnash.

Comment: Hi philnash is it possible to get the conference call duration using conference sid. i try the following process. conference = client.account.conferences.get("conferencesid")
puts conference.duration. But it is not work for me

Comment: I need to do payment based on the conference call duration. Please advice me what i have did wrong in above code or please provide some details to get duration or full detail of conference call.

Comment: A conference itself doesn't have a duration. A conference is made up of one or more calls. If you setup the code like I wrote above to get a webhook when the conference starts, it will be sent for each call in the conference and will also include the `CallSid` parameter. Using the `CallSid` you can then look up how long each call was part of the conference using the [Calls API resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call) which will give you a duration for each call.

Comment: Thanks philnash, that is what i have did currently in my application, so i will go with that process. Thank you for your response.